# Retrieve result using recursive queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, recursive-query

I have a table which maintain version of record with their parent id
Eg

```
Table(Id,version,parentId)
```

I am trying to get all the related record from given Id value

```
;WITH CTE (Id,ParentId)
AS
(
Select T1.Id,T1.ParentId
From Table T1
Where T1.ID = @Id or T1.ParentId=@Id

Union All

Select T2.Id, T2.ParentId
From Table T2
     Inner Join CTE C on C.Id= T2.ParentId  
)
```

This works fine for when the main parent id ***(162527)*** is provided, it brings me the

```
Id      VersionNo   ParentId
162527      1.0         0
162530      1.1         162527
162531      1.2         162527
162532      1.2.1       162531
162533      1.2.1.1     162532
162534      1.2.2       162531
200346      1.2.2.1     162534
200354      1.2.2.1.1   200346
```

But When I pass ***200354*** as Id, it returns me

```
200346  1.2.2.1     162534
200354  1.2.2.1.1   200346
```

But I want the all related record when an id is given.

Any help

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
declare @Table table (id int, parentid int)

declare @id int, @ParentId int

select @id = 162530 

insert into @Table
select 162527, 0 union all
select 162530, 162527 union all
select 162531, 162527 union all
select 162532, 162531 union all
select 162533, 162532 union all
select 162534, 162531 union all
select 200346, 162534 union all
select 200354, 200346

;WITH Parents
AS
(
    Select T1.Id, T1.ParentId from @Table T1 where Id = @Id
    Union All
    Select T2.Id, T2.ParentId
    From @Table T2 Inner Join Parents C on C.ParentId = T2.Id
)
select @ParentId = P.id
from Parents as P
where parentid = 0

;WITH Children
AS
(
    Select T1.Id, T1.ParentId from @Table T1 where Id = @ParentId
    Union All
    Select T2.Id, T2.ParentId
    From @Table T2 Inner Join Children C on C.Id = T2.parentid
)
select *
from Children
```

Previous one

```
;WITH Children (Id,ParentId)
AS
(
    Select T1.Id, T1.ParentId from @Table T1 where Id = @Id
    Union All
    Select T2.Id, T2.ParentId
    From @Table T2 Inner Join Children C on C.ParentId = T2.Id
),Parents (Id,ParentId)
AS
(
    Select T1.Id, T1.ParentId from @Table T1 where Id = @Id
    Union All
    Select T2.Id, T2.ParentId
    From @Table T2 Inner Join Parents C on C.Id = T2.parentId
)
select * from Parents
union
select * from Children
```

Comment: This leads to an error **The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion**

Comment: @huMptyduMpty, you can add OPTION (MAXRECURSION N) to the select from the CTE to raise the recursion limit to N(assuming the query proposed above is correct and you only need to get past the recursion limit)

Comment: @cravoori: I tried with OPTION (MAXRECURSION 200) which still gives me the same error, when I try OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0) it is keep running (never ending loop)

Comment: @RomanPekar: I am not sure what the issue here is, I tried you new one with id **162530** which only brings the ids(162527,162530)

Comment: @huMptyduMpty and what it should return?

Comment: @RomanPekar, "where Id = @Id" in the Children CTE should be changed to "where ParentID = @Id"

Comment: Yes it could work, but I think my way would work too, buy anyway, there's `union` and not `union all`, so there is only distinct records

Comment: @RomanPekar: No matter whatever value bee passed, it should reutn all related records as I mentioned in the question

Comment: @huMptyduMpty but I see only two records related to **162530**.
record **162530** is 1.1, it has no children, only parent 1.0. If I'm not right then may be you comment about what do you mean by related

Comment: @RomanPekar: Yes, but its parent have sub records which i need to pickup. I think if its possible to trackdown the record until where a record have parentid =0, that record id can passed to the current code i am using. But I am not quite sure how to achieve it

Comment: So your goal is to get all records, that are children of topmost parent of current record?

Comment: @huMptyduMpty I've edited a query, but it's two statements - first i'm getting top ParentId then I get all of children. A little bit weird task :)